# MongoDB C# Driver Is Slow On First Connection Initialize

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, connection

We have an application running on IIS, using mongodb c# drivers, (2.11.5.0 version), when it is opening a new connection to the replicaset, it takes about **500 ms** (including a database listing operation),

At the same environment and same machine i tried the same case with a NodeJS application, it establishes the connection and lists the databases in **62 ms**. I also tried with python code and it takes **12 ms** including getting a record from a collection.
(Everytime i control these durations, i close all the connections to mongodb and stop these applications first)

In our environment the first connection initialize slowness is problem because there are servers behind load balancers, and if there are not enough requests coming to all servers and keep connections open, even if i set idle timeout to a longer time like 20 minutes, the request can be forwarded to an idle server and 500 ms additional duration is a cost for the transaction.  And in our case the transaction response time should be less than 250 ms.

The NodeJS code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
async function listDatabases(client){
    databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();
};
async function main(){
 
    const uri = "mongodb://dbUserName:dbPassword@SERVER/DBName?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=false&replicaSet=replicaName&authSource=admin";
    
    console.time("listDatabaseNamesDuration");

    const client = new MongoClient(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
 
    try {
    
        await client.connect();
 
        await  listDatabases(client);

        console.timeEnd("listDatabaseNamesDuration");

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
main();
```

C# Code:

```
       var credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(databaseName: "admin",
       username: "dbUserName",
       password: "dbPassword");
            IList<MongoServerAddress> serverList = new List<MongoServerAddress>();
            serverList.Add(new MongoServerAddress("serverName", portNumber));
            MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Servers = serverList,
                ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet,
                ReplicaSetName = "replicasetName",
                Credential = credential,
                UseTls = false,
            };

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            MongoClient _client = new MongoClient(settings);
            _client.ListDatabaseNames();
            sw.Stop();
            output.ListDatabaseNamesDuration = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

first try caching or making the `MongoClient` a singleton. if that doesn't help, try configuring the tcp connections to `KeepAlive` as follows:

```cs
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    Servers = serverList,
    ReplicaSetName = "replicasetName",
    Credential = credential,
    UseTls = false,
};

settings.ClusterConfigurator =
    b => b.ConfigureTcp(
        tcp => tcp.With(
            socketConfigurator:
                (Action<Socket>)(
                    s => s.SetSocketOption(
                        SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                        SocketOptionName.KeepAlive,
                        true))));

var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

best to make the `MongoClient` a singleton as that's what's recommended in the mongo docs.